# What assumptions on $f: X \to Y$ such that $\Delta: X \to X \times_Y X$ is a closed immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X, Y$ be separated schemes and  $f: X \to Y$ a morphism of schemes. 
Is it then always the case that $f$ is separated
(i.e. $\Delta: X \to X \times_Y X$ is a closed immersion)?

Comment: The way this question is worded is puzzling to me. It looks as if you're unfamiliar with the definition of a separated morphism as one where the corresponding map $\Delta$ is a closed immersion - is this so? Or do you know this and you're asking for conditions on two schemes which guarantee that any morphism between them is separated? In either case, please consider adding context so we can better help you.

Comment: Let me fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be morphisms of schemes. If $g\circ f$ is separated, then $f$ is separated.

**Proof**: Consider the factorization of the diagonal morphism $X\to X\times_Y X\to X\times_Z X$. The second map is an immersion: $X\times_Y X\to X\times_Z X$ is the base change of $\Delta:Y\to Y\times_Z Y$ along $X\times_Z X\to Y\times_Z Y$, and the base change of an immersion is an immersion. As the composite $X\to X\times_Y X\to X\times_Z X$ is a closed immersion by assumption, we see that $X\to X\times_Y X$ must also be a closed immersion. $\blacksquare$

To apply this to your situation, all you need is that $X$ is separated (or more generally, $X$ and $Y$ are $Z$-schemes with $f$ a $Z$-morphism and $X$ separated over $Z$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When you say "immersion" do you mean a closed immersion or something else?

Comment: A morphism of schemes is called an immersion if it can be factored as $j\circ i$, a composition of a closed immersion $i$ and an open immersion $j$. With this definition it is easy to see that the inclusion of any locally closed subscheme is an immersion, which has an obvious application to the diagonal morphism.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why if the composition $A \to B \to C$ is a closed immersion and $B \to C$ is an immersion, then $A \to B$ is a closed immersion? ($A,B,C$ schemes) I'm not quite seeing this part of the argument... thank you

Comment: @JohnnyT. Two facts to know: an immersion is a homeomorphism onto its image and an immersion $f:X\to Y$ is a closed immersion iff $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$. So $A\subset C$ is closed, which means $A\subset B$ must be closed, and then we're done.

Comment: Thank you very much!